# How to create arrays for each values - PHP

Tags: php

```
// ARRAY
(
    [apple] => one
    [orange] => two
    [strawberry] => three
)

// NEW ARRAY
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => orange 
            [1] => two
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => strawberry
            [1] => three
        )

)
```

I want to create an array for each key of the current array, so i can use this in a foreach later. Is it possible?

I've tried everything without success.

Comment: This is possible, but why can't you use the array you already have in your `foreach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through every elements in your associative array and create an empty array before the loop. Then push the key as well as value to the new array. This way you can get that desirable output:

```php
<?php

$assocArray = [
    "apple" => "one",
    "orange" => "two",
    "strawberry" => "three"
];

echo "Before: \n\r";
print_r($assocArray);

$newArray = [];

foreach ($assocArray as $key => $item) {
    $newArray[] = [$key, $item];
}

echo "After: \n\r";
print_r($newArray);
```

#### Output

```
Before: 
Array
(
    [apple] => one
    [orange] => two
    [strawberry] => three
)
After: 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => orange
            [1] => two
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => strawberry
            [1] => three
        )

)
``
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do that $newArray[] = [$key, $item]... Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
$array = [
    'apple' => 'one',
    'orange' => 'two',
    'strawberry' => 'three',
];

$output = array_map(function($k, $v) {
    return [$k, $v];
}, array_keys($array), $array);

var_dump($output);
```